# How to show that $A,I,I_A$ all lie on same line?

Tags: geometry

In triangle ABC suppose we join AI (I is incentre ) and $II_A$ ($I_A$ is excentre) , how can we say that <$AII_A$ is 180 ° ( that is they lie on a straight line . Or in other way how to show that $AI$ line extension and $AI_A$ cuts $BC$ at same point I did angle chasing on BIC hut i wasnt able to find the the specific angles which can tell the sum of the angles to be 180° for that II_A line.[image]

Comment: What kind of point is $I_A$?

Comment: This question is trivial if you think the definition (one of) of $I_A$.

Comment: @Arthur I think it is escentre

Comment: Oh yeah its excentre i will edit

Comment: @JetfiRex which definition can you hint ?

Comment: @ProblemDestroyer One definition of incenter is "the intersection of three angular bisector", and one definition of excentre is "the intersection of the angular bisector of $A$ and the angular bisectors of complement angles of $B$ and $C$". In this definition, it is obvious $A,I,I_A$ are collinear, they are all on the angular bisector of $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $D$ be the midpoint of arc $BC$, then points $A,I,D$ are collinear.
$$\angle DBI=\angle IBC + \angle CBD=\angle ABI + \angle IAC=\angle ABI + \angle IAB=\angle BID$$
Hence $\triangle BID$ is isosceles with $BD=ID$. By the same argument $ID=DC$.
Since $$\angle IBI_A=\angle ICI_A=90^\circ$$ points $B,I,C,I_A$ are concyclic with center $D$. But $II_A$ is the diameter, therefore $I,D,I_A$ are collinear, and the result follows.

Comment: That is good explanation thanks .